# Hive: Will SMB Join work if I bucket on 2 columns but use only one column in Joining condition

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, bigdata

SMB requires that both tables are bucketed on the same columns and also sorted. What if I have bucketing on 2 columns say ColA and ColB of both tables, but I use only ColA as joining column. Will SMB work in this case? How will it behave in this case?